# Solving 8-puzzle game using DFS

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am trying to solve the 8-puzzle problem with DFS starting from this code implemented with BFS. What is the easiest approach of doing it? All the codes I've researched are either working and incomplete which sheds me into more of a confusion than I was before.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

class EightPuzzle {

Queue<String> agenda = new LinkedList<String>();    // Use of Queue Implemented using LinkedList for Storing All the Nodes in BFS.
Map<String,Integer> stateDepth = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // HashMap is used to ignore repeated nodes
Map<String,String> stateHistory = new HashMap<String,String>(); // relates each position to its predecessor

public static void main(String args[]){

    String str="087465132";                                 // Input the Board State as a String with 0 as the Blank Space

    EightPuzzle e = new EightPuzzle();              // New Instance of the EightPuzzle
    e.add(str, null);                                                   // Add the Initial State

    while(!e.agenda.isEmpty()){
        String currentState = e.agenda.remove();
        e.up(currentState);                                       // Move the blank space up and add new state to queue
        e.down(currentState);                                     // Move the blank space down
        e.left(currentState);                                     // Move left
        e.right(currentState);                          // Move right and remove the current node from Queue
    }

    System.out.println("Solution doesn't exist");
}

//Add method to add the new string to the Map and Queue
void add(String newState, String oldState){
    if(!stateDepth.containsKey(newState)){
        int newValue = oldState == null ? 0 : stateDepth.get(oldState) + 1;
        stateDepth.put(newState, newValue);
        agenda.add(newState);
        stateHistory.put(newState, oldState);
    }
}

/* Each of the Methods below Takes the Current State of Board as String. Then the operation to move the blank space is done if possible.
  After that the new string is added to the map and queue.If it is the Goal State then the Program Terminates.
 */
void up(String currentState){
    int a = currentState.indexOf("0");
    if(a>2){
        String nextState = currentState.substring(0,a-3)+"0"+currentState.substring(a-2,a)+currentState.charAt(a-3)+currentState.substring(a+1);
        checkCompletion(currentState, nextState);
    }
}

void down(String currentState){
    int a = currentState.indexOf("0");
    if(a<6){
        String nextState = currentState.substring(0,a)+currentState.substring(a+3,a+4)+currentState.substring(a+1,a+3)+"0"+currentState.substring(a+4);
        checkCompletion(currentState, nextState);
    }
}
void left(String currentState){
    int a = currentState.indexOf("0");
    if(a!=0 && a!=3 && a!=6){
        String nextState = currentState.substring(0,a-1)+"0"+currentState.charAt(a-1)+currentState.substring(a+1);
        checkCompletion(currentState, nextState);
    }
}
void right(String currentState){
    int a = currentState.indexOf("0");
    if(a!=2 && a!=5 && a!=8){
        String nextState = currentState.substring(0,a)+currentState.charAt(a+1)+"0"+currentState.substring(a+2);
        checkCompletion(currentState, nextState);
    }
}

private void checkCompletion(String oldState, String newState) {
    add(newState, oldState);
    if(newState.equals("123456780")) {
        System.out.println("Solution Exists at Level "+stateDepth.get(newState)+" of the tree");
        String traceState = newState;
        while (traceState != null) {
            System.out.println(traceState + " at " + stateDepth.get(traceState));
            traceState = stateHistory.get(traceState);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

DFS isn't the best way to solve the 8-puzzle but,

With that code, you should be able to implement it as DFS by only changing the main method, nextState and adding a goDepth method.

I recommend analyzing this code, then try visualizing how it works on paper. After you understand exactly how it works, you can implement the DFS algorithm in it without a problem.

Comment: I know it isn't though that's what I have to use and it's tedious, a lisp version of it takes too long to run to find out if it's working or not.. hence I'm trying this.